# Apache user account passwordless access to the server - Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ssh, rsync

I have the same issue which is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089350/rsync-via-php-exec-with-ssh-passwordless-ssh-login) question. If I explain it again, I can use rsync to sync my local data with the server without password (I used SSH keys). But when I use exec() function in PHP, it doesn't work.

The person who has asked the above question has given the answer by himself. He says it can be done by allowing the Apache user account passwordless access to the serve. So my question is **how do I provide Apache user account passwordless access to the server**?

My PHP code is :

```
echo exec('rsync -aze  --progress --size-only /var/tmp/src/File01 serveruser@mycloud.com.lk:/var/tmp/dest/File01');
```

PS: I logged into my machine using my typical user account (Let say username is '**bob**'), and generated ssh keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` . Then **bob** has passwordless access to server.

But,When I run PHP command, it runs in Apache under `mod_php` and Usually Apache is running as its own user account, independent from the real-world people who use the server. Therefore my generated keys are not available to PHP inside Apache.

Therefore I tried to login as Apache user (I think it is *www-data*). But most of the articles says *www-data* doesn't have a password by default and cannot login as *www-data*.

Comment: Good question. possible duplicate of [Sync local and remote folders using rsync from php script without typing password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775220/sync-local-and-remote-folders-using-rsync-from-php-script-without-typing-passwor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the Apache user cannot access my keys. Therefore I had to generate SSH keys for the Apache user (it's www-data) although it was not so secure. First login as root.

```
mkdir /var/www/.ssh
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh
```

Now generate SSH keys as following. It will save your private key and public key in `/var/www/.ssh` folder:

```
sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Now you should get something like this:

```
root@sampath-Vostro-1520:/var/www/.ssh# sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx www-data@machine-Vostro-1520
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|       ...o...o..|
|           o..  o|
|         + .. .+o|
|         .  .*o+o|
|     ++ S   ..B..|
|         o . E + |
|        . . o o  |
|             . . |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Now copy your public key to the remote server:

```
sudo -u www-data ssh-copy-id -i /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@myserver.com
```

Now this should work. :-)

```
<?php
$c='rsync -azv /source/folder/path/ username@myserver.com:/destination/folder/path';
exec($c,$data);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: You're the best! I was looking for the way for few hours already and thank to you I finally did it. The funny thing is, I had the same idea like 2 hours ago, but I forgot that rsa_key is owned by user of unix system. And I just copied rsa_key from my home directory to www-data one and I had no idea why it doesn't work. :) Thank you again.

Comment: I have tried that, but I always get mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/root/.ssh/ssh-copy-id_id.XXXXXXXXXX’: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Normally your key is loaded via an SSH agent making it automatically available, instead of using this you can manually specify an identity file. If you generate a key to use, as long as it's readable by apache then it can be used.

Rsync doesn't let you specific the identiy file directly but you can pass parameters to the underlying SSH call:

```
echo exec('rsync -az -e "ssh -i /var/www/key.pri" --progress --size-only /var/tmp/src/File01 serveruser@mycloud.com.lk:/var/tmp/dest/File01');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't work. I don't know what is the problem with this. but following command again work well on the terminal, but not with exec(). `rsync -az -e "ssh -i /var/www/id_rsa" --progress /var/tmp/src/File01 serveruser@mycloud.com.lk:/var/tmp/dest/File01`

Comment: Do you get any output when running it? Should give you an error if the key isn't available or it can't access the server.

Comment: No. It doesn't give any message. echo doesn't print anything.