# synchronize database with `mysqlddump` through `exec()` in php

Tags: php, mysql, exec

I'm trying to synchronize the databases on the localhost with the one on a server by copying the database to the local machine.

I have the following shell command which works without issues in the terminal:

```
ssh user@server "mysqldump -u user -p'secret' db-name" | mysql -u local_user -p'secret' db-name
```

The ssh login has been automated with a passphrase like in [question@Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password).

I've tried executing this command throug `exec()` in php, but I don't get any results.

```
exec(ssh user@server "mysqldump -u user -p'secret' db-name" | mysql -u local_user -p'secret' db-name)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: PHP sounds like the wrong tool for the job: cron - perhaps in combination with something like rsync - would probably make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The `www-data` user couldn't login with the generated key. (invalid permissions)

The answer to [Apache user account passwordless access to the server - Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712778/apache-user-account-passwordless-access-to-the-server-ubuntu) resulted in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh_exec` instead ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php)).

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
?>
```